# What "other races" make sense for Trunau?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races, adventure-path

I'm looking at page 8 of...

> *Battle of Bloodmarch Hill*

(PZO9091), the first book of the *Giantslayer* campaign - namely the town statistics for Trunau.

The population is made of a large number of humans and of several other core races, with the less featured being gnome (10 gnomes in Trunau) and elves (at least one elf, Silvermane, is a long-time resident of Trunau) being grouped in the generic "other" entry.

So, I suppose there might be 25 different races with one exemplar each or, at the other end of the spectrum, at least three races with at most 9 individual inhabitants each (9+9+7 or 9+8+8).

We also know that no full-blooded orcs live in Trunau, only half-orcs, so the main race of the Belkzen region is out.

Are some other races officially represented in Trunau? As in, **is there any published material that tells us that some individual of any other race lives there?**

If not, is there any hint to what kind of creatures could be the most probable residents of those at least two other races?

Answer (score 1):

The write-up of Belkzen mentions that trade comes in from Lastwall and Nirmathas, which means that **Chelaxian tieflings** are a possibility, as well as **centaurs, gathlains**, and **ghorans**. It doesn't mention Varisia, but with that big of a border, there has to be some overlap, and with that would come **stone giants**.

Within the Hold of Belkzen itself, there are **mongrelmen, taiga giants, freshwater merrow, ogrekin,** and various **fleshwarped humanoids**.

Comment: I think all sorts of giants are also outside of Trunau's regular population. Gathlains and Ghorans might even live in the nearby forests, following the river downstream. Good idea.